# DhtmlxGrid render table with connector behaviour

Tags: java, mysql, dhtmlx

I am using java connector for DHTMLXGrid. I want to render a table and display only those record where value of some field is some.Just like `"Select * from table where status='inProgress';"` 
Currently I am doing

```
Connection conn= ( new DataBaseConnection()).getConnection();

        GridConnector c = new GridConnector(conn);
        c.dynamic_loading(100);
        c.render_table("grid50000", "item_id", "item_nm,item_cd,status");
    }
```

What I want is select those record `where item_nm like %ro%` 
Does any have any solution.

I have used

```
class FilterBehavior extends ConnectorBehavior {
            public void beforeRender(DataItem data) {
                if (data == null || !data.get_value("status").equalsIgnoreCase("inProgress")) {
                    data.skip();
                }
            }
        }
        c.event.attach(new FilterBehavior());
```

but data item which have status other than "inProgress" still populates.